# Css wrap content together according to text inside

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I am not really into Css and I am having hard time to wrap all content together inside the tabs , I would really appreciate if someone can advice how to make it , so far I been able to style it a bit  but I can`t really make it work properly

```
    <style type="text/css">
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
    background:#FFF;  
}
#page-wrap {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  font: 13px/1 'Open Sans', arial;
  background:#FFF;
}
    .tabs {
      position: relative;   
      min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
      clear:both;
      margin: 25px 0;
      border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
      background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #f7f7f7;
      font:13px/1 'Open Sans', arial;
      color:#868883;
      max-width:1500px;

    }
    .tab {
        /*height: 40px;*/
        width:20%; 
    }
    .tab label {
      display:block;
      cursor:pointer;
      margin:auto;
      border:1px solid #dcdcdc; 
      padding-left:28px;
      border-top:none !important;
      height:56px;
      line-height:54px;
      text-align:left;
      text-decoration:none;
      text-transform:uppercase;
    }
    .tab label:hover {
    color:#000;
}
    .tab [type=radio] {
      display: none;   
    }
    .content {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 200px;
      background: white;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    [type=radio]:checked ~ label {
      background: white;
      z-index: 2;
      font-size:13px;
      color:#000;
    }
    [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
      z-index: 1;
    }
</style>
```

Also the container height need to be the same size without any scroolbar ,

This is the Html and css code I use 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stefanoste/5x8o1ntb/)

Basically I need to wrap all tabs according to the text inside like the example below

```
  <style>
    .tabs {
      font-size: 0;
      margin: 25px 0;
    }

    .tabs:after {
      clear: both;
      content: '';
      display: table;
    }

    .tabs .tab {
      display: inline;
    }

    .tabs .tab-label {
      background: #eee; 
      border: 1px solid #ccc; 
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-size: 1rem;
      left: 1px;
      margin-left: -1px;
      padding: 10px; 
      position: relative;
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }

    .tabs .tab > [type="radio"] {
      clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
      height: 1px;
      opacity: 0;
      position: fixed;
      width: 1px;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    .tabs .tab-panel {
      display: inline;
      display: inline-block;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      height: 0;
      width: 0;
    }

    .tabs .tab-content {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: block;
      background: white;
      padding: 0 20px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      float: left;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-size: 1rem;
      margin-top: -1px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .tabs .tab [type="radio"]:checked + .tab-label {
      background: white;
      border-bottom-width: 0;
      padding-bottom: 11px;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .tabs .tab [type="radio"]:checked ~ .tab-panel {
      display: inline;
    }

      </style>

    <div class="tabs">

      <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-1">Huh? Tabs again?</label>

        <div class="tab-panel">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <h3>Why would this be cool?</h3>
            <p>First look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'First look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This mFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'First look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This muFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'First look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This muFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'First look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This muFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'First look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This muFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'First look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This muFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'First look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This muFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'First look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This muust be done by Chris Coyier'sFirst look at the HTML structure: all elements related to one tab are within one block. Now think about that for a while. This must be done by Chris Coyier'ss <a href="http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/">Functional CSS Tabs Revisited</a> already, right?</p>
            <p>Maybe. But then you may notice another thing: Chris' example uses absolute positioning for the content. This means the tabs must be of fixed height. Yet these tabs here certainly aren't!</p>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-2">Variable height content</label>

        <div class="tab-panel">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <h3>What is this devilry?</h3>
            <p>First of all we are working with inline content here and being smart about it. We eliminate white space using the dirty but sufficient zero font-size.</p>
            <p>There is one additional element in comparison to what Chris had: <code>.tab-panel</code> element, which works as a container for the <code>.tab-content</code> element. The panel is inline-block by default, which means it can take styles like overflow, position, and width and height. We set these to zero size, use <code>overflow: hidden;</code> and <code>position: relative;</code> so that <code>.tab-content</code> disappears. For the active tab we do only one style change and it happens to the <code>.tab-panel</code> element: we make it inline! Thus it no longer follows the other rules that bind inline-block. As a result it's child element will start following the flow of the next container element up in the tree.</p>
            <p>As for the <code>.tab-content</code> element it is floated and has a width of 100%. The neat thing about this combination is that it forces the element to go below the row where you can see the tab buttons.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tab">
        <input class="tab-radio" type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
        <label class="tab-label" for="tab-3">Browser support</label>
        <div class="tab-panel">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <h3>The support must be poor!</h3>
            <p>The CSS only part of this solution works in Internet Explorer 9+. All the other browsers are supported from so far back that it is enough to tell this works on Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera.</p>
            <p>The JavaScript is quite simple and it is for IE8 and below. It does no harm to other browsers, but you probably want to hide it behind IE conditional comments: <code>&lt;!--[if lte IE 8]&gt; &hellip; &lt;![endif]--&gt;</code></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

THX

Comment: If you don't want to show it on scroll, are you okay to have a popup instead?

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/5x8o1ntb/5/ with a popup

Comment: Thank you but I don`t need the pop up , I just want to make it wrap all together

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.content{overflow-y: scroll;}
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term value.
Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what
limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: No it does`t solve the problem ,because I would like without the scroll ..I need to wrap all tabs according to the text inside

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:auto` to `.content` like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5x8o1ntb/2/)**

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

**Update**:

Try to add `display none` for `content` and `block` once its `checked` **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5x8o1ntb/4/)**

```
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
    display:block;
}

.content {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Also the container height  need to be the same size  without any scroolbar

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you wrap Content:

```
.content {
      word-wrap:break-word;
      overflow:hidden
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 200px;
      background: white;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!